# SQL Server returns ??? when column is updated with Thai characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, character-encoding, collation, codepages

I updated a column with Thai characters. When selecting from it, it returns: `???`.  I  tried to set the collation to `Thai_CI_AS` but it's still not working.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a lot of information provided in the question. All we know is:

- Column is using Collation of `Thai_CI_AS` (at least that it was it sounds like the question is stating)
- Thai characters are being passed in
- What is stored in the column is: `???`

However, from that alone we can deduce two things:

1. The incoming string is neither an `NVARCHAR` parameter / variable, nor is it a string literal that is prefixed with an upper-case "N",

   *and*
2. The default Collation for the DB in which the query is being executed (not necessarily the DB in which the Table exists) is *not* a Thai Collation.

We do not know if the destination column is `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`, but that doesn't matter if the Collation of the column is a Thai Collation (since that will allow `VARCHAR` data to hold Thai characters, and `NVARCHAR` would work regardless).

If *either*:

- the incoming string uses an `NVARCHAR` parameter (or if string literal, then prefix with an upper-case "N"),

  *or*
- the query were executed in a DB that has a Thai default Collation

then the Thai characters would get stored as expected.

The following example demonstrates this behavior. I use a [Thai Character Khomut U+0E5B](https://unicode-table.com/en/0E5B/) on an instance having a `Korean_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC` Instance-level default Collation. The destination column has a Collation of `Thai_CI_AS`. First, while the "current" DB is one that does *not* have a Thai default Collation, I add the character twice: once prefixed with "N" and once with no prefix on the string literal:

```
USE [tempdb];
-- DROP TABLE #Thai;
CREATE TABLE #Thai (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Col1 VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Thai_CI_AS);

-- In a DB with a non-Thai default Collation:
INSERT INTO #Thai (Col1) VALUES ('๛');
INSERT INTO #Thai (Col1) VALUES (N'๛');
```

Next, I switch to a DB that *does* have a Thai default Collation and insert just the non-prefixed string (no real need to re-test the "N"-prefixed string):

```
USE [other_db];

-- In a DB with a Thai default Collation:
INSERT INTO #Thai (Col1) VALUES ('๛');


SELECT * FROM #Thai;
```

The result is:

```
ID  Col1
1   ?
2   ๛
3   ๛
```

As you can see (point # below relates to ID # in results above):

1. The non-"N"-prefixed string, used in a DB using a non-Thai default Collation, got translated into `?`
2. The "N"-prefixed string, also used in a DB using a non-Thai default Collation, stored the value correctly
3. The non-"N"-prefixed string, used in a DB that does have a Thai default Collation, stored the value correctly