# How to make SQL server recognize unique Thai characters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here's my table:

```
 id      name
 1     ទឹក កាបូន 
 2     លីអូ បៀរ 
 3     ស្របៀរ ២៤ 
 4     ស្រាបៀរ ឌ្រាប់
```

When I query using this statement: `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE name = N'លីអូ បៀរ'`, it returns all rows. This is weird since those Thai characters are different.

Also, this will cause an issue if I make the name column as unique. Does anyone encounter the same issue and what is the possible fix? I tried changing the collation but still no avail.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269660/sql-server-returns-when-column-is-updated-with-thai-characters

Comment: Tried changing the collation to what, and how? You can't change collation of a column after the table has been created, without recreating the table. Notably, changing the database collation has no effect on existing objects, only on how literals are compared.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the schema of the table.

Answer (score 2):

> How to make SQL server recognize unique Thai characters?

Bing translate identifies those characters as Khmer, not Thai.  So you need to pick a collation that has language-specific rules for those characters, eg

```
drop table if exists t1

create table t1(id int, name nvarchar(200) collate Khmer_100_CI_AI )

insert into t1(id,name)
values (1, N'ទឹក កាបូន'),(2, N'លីអូ បៀរ'),(3, N'ស្របៀរ ២៤'),(4, N'ស្រាបៀរ ឌ្រាប់')

SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE name = N'លីអូ បៀរ'
```

Or use binary collation, that simply compares the characters by their code point values. eg

```
drop table if exists t1

create table t1(id int, name nvarchar(200) collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2 )

insert into t1(id,name)
values (1, N'ទឹក កាបូន'),(2, N'លីអូ បៀរ'),(3, N'ស្របៀរ ២៤'),(4, N'ស្រាបៀរ ឌ្រាប់')

SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE name = N'លីអូ បៀរ'
```

Even some of the newer Latin collations will work, eg

```
drop table if exists t1

create table t1(id int, name nvarchar(200) collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AI )

insert into t1(id,name)
values (1, N'ទឹក កាបូន'),(2, N'លីអូ បៀរ'),(3, N'ស្របៀរ ២៤'),(4, N'ស្រាបៀរ ឌ្រាប់')

SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE name = N'លីអូ បៀរ'
```